# Custom Content Entity Bundles - How to override class methods?

Tags: 8, entities

I created a custom content entity type and a bundle of this entity type. The custom content entity is presented as PHP class; the entity bundle is defined in a configuration file.

I created the Entity class on my own, programmatically; the entity bundle was created via the Drupal UI.

Now I am wondering why Drupal is creating a configuration file instead of a subclass. Do you know if it is possible to override class methods from the base entity for the specific entity bundle?

Comment: The Entity API was not intended for the use case that you are describing.  Bundles are meant to describe different _configurations_ of an Entity type, but not different _functionally_. There a couple of patterns that have been used, even in Drupal 7, to do such, but it in Drupal 8, but that's an opinionated answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know if it is possible to override class methods from the base
>   entity for the specific entity bundle?

Yes, this is possible. In code you can only override globally, but a class instance is always bundle specific. This is the only required field when creating a content entity with bundles. So the bundle is always set and you can use it in a condition in the overridden method and defer to the parent method for other bundles.

For example if you had a getTitle() method you could modify the title for a specific bundle:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getTitle() {
    if ($this->bundle() == 'foo') {
      return 'bar';
    }

    return parent::getTitle();
  }
```